# How to return SQL statement that caused an exception from a stored procedure to SSIS

Tags: ssis

We have a SSIS package that calls a stored procedure through an EXECUTE SQL TASK component. The stored procedure contains a LOT of different pieces of sql code that gets build dynamically and then executed via exec strSQL within the stored procedure. The whole system is built that way and we cannot redesigned at this point. The problem is that when something fails within the stored procedure is hard to figure out from SSIS what SQL statement from the stored procedure caused the exception/failure. What we have right now and is working is the package onError event with code to read the System::ErrorDescription which is helpful to display the error in SSIS and then send an email with the error, this is working. What I'm looking for to add is to have a System Variable or some other way to display the actual SQL (the one that caused the exception within the stored procedure) in SSIS to I can include that in the email. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution. Table variables are not roled back in a catch block and rollback statement.

So put the sql statements before they run into a table varaible with an nvarchar (max) datatype. Make sure your proc uses try catch blocks and transactions. In the catch block, perform a rollback if need be and then insert the contents of the table variable and a datetime to a logging table. NOw you have a record of exactly what queries were run. You can also create a separate table varaible to store the data you are attempting to insert or update if that is also an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Is there a way to do this without rolling back transactions from the stored procedure? Right now our code does not have any transactions within stored proc and also our code does not have try catch statements anywhere, I know that that should be changed but I'm trying to find the least complicated way of doing this so the hours of effort for this are approved. How would I read the table variable from within SSIS thought? Somehow I need to get that data from table variable to SSIS (SSIS variable) so I can grab the sql and stick it into the email task.

Comment: You add it to the proc and insert to a permananent log table. Then the ssis apackage can pull the info from that table into a varaiable with an exec SQL task. You can do it without try catch, but then you have data integrity issues if the thing doesn't work properly and it does inserts or updates, so I highly recommend you fix the proc.

Answer (score 1):

When you run a package by using F5 and a SQL statement fails you can check the execution results tab, but unfortunately this only shows the first line or two of your SQL statement.

Instead of running the package by using F5, run it using Crtl+F5. This will open a terminal window and run the package as though it was called from the command line. As each task runs it will output log information, if the task uses a SQL statement and it fails it will output the full SQL statement.

Ctrl+F5 is called 'Start Without Debugging' yet I always think it is a better to debug a package.